# On the difference $\operatorname{Li}(\theta(x))-\pi(x)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-number-theorem

In G. Robin's paper, more precisely in Lemme12, how does he use formula (39) to prove formula (36)?

[1] Robin, Guy, "Estimation de la fonction de Tchebychef  θ  sur le  k -ième nombre premier et grandes valeurs de la fonction  ω(n)  nombre de diviseurs premiers de  n , Acta Arithmetica 42, 367-389 (1983). MR0736719, ZBL0475.10034.

The paper is available at 
https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/acta-arithmetica/all/42

Lemme 12 states,

Nous avons les majorations suivantes: Pour $x\ge2$ 
$${\pi(x)\log\theta(x)\over\theta(x)}\le1+{1\over\log\theta(x)}+{2,89726\over\log^2\theta(x)}\tag{36}$$ avec egalite pour $x=p_{442}$, 
$${\pi(x)\log\theta(x)\over\theta(x)}\le1+{1\over\log x}+{2,96690\over\log^2 x}\tag{37}$$ avec egalite pour $x=p_{224}-0$.

Formula (39) is:

$$\int_2^x{\theta(t)\over t\log^2t}\,dt\le{x\over\log^2x}\left(1+{2,843\over\log x}\right)$$

Comment: (Okay, it seems the OP has tried to ask this question twice before; the first time it was closed with one reason being that more details are needed. I believe that OP is trying in good faith to provide details; the problem is in the deleting and then reasking in another post. Technically, this is a site violation.) To the OP: in future, please do not delete and reask; instead, edit the original question to improve it.

Comment: Why don't you start from a strong form of the PNT, say $|\theta(t)-t|\le A t/\log^2 t,|\pi(t)-\sum_{n\le t} 1/\log n|\le B t/\log^3 t$, you'll obtain that 36 is true for $t\ge T$ so you can check numerically for $t\le T$.

Comment: It doesn't seem clear to me either. If all the $\log\theta(x)$ terms were $\log x$, I can see Robin's method working; but at the very least, how $\log\theta(x)$ is dealt with is inadequately explained.

Comment: My problem is how to use them?